# Can i use ListView as root element?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm just starting with android and have a little question.

I want to use a ListView - i don't need any buttons or something like this stuff.

Can i use a ListView as a root element or are there any disadvantages? In each tutorial RelativeLayout or LinearLayout were used as a root element.

Thanks ;)

Comment: Have you looked at extending ListActivity?

Comment: Yes - but my app works without extending ListActivity... my question is, are there any advantages when using relativeLayout or LinearLayout as root element ;)

Comment: Use a simple `ListView`, this way you'll flatten the view hierarchy and improve performance.

Comment: If the ListView is empty (i.e. there is nothing to show) and if you intend to show a custom message, then you need to wrap your ListView within a container (like RelativeLayout/LinearLayout) and have an additional view in the container. See this [`post`](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/06/20/listview-tips-tricks-1-handle-emptiness/)